# Ride getting stuck if the test suites are being executed as process

Tags: python, robotframework, ride

```
${is_success}=  Run And Return Rc   pybot -d ${results_dir} -o sample.xml sample_test.tsv                                                           
${is_sanity_pass}=  Set Variable If ${is_success} != 0  Failed  ${is_sanity_pass}
```

Comment: I am trying to execute the Entire suite and get the status of the  suite, but the ride gets stuck in the execution and not getting time out

Comment: So, if you run in the command line, or Terminal or bash, outside of RIDE, the behaviour is the expected?
Also,`pybot`e the very old name of `robot` and you did not mention what version of RIDE and what OS.

Comment: I don't see what RIDE has to do with this. RIDE is just an IDE. Does this problem happen outside of using the IDE (ie: when running the test from the command line)?

Comment: yes, I have tried replacing 'pybot' command by 'robot', but still the suite is getting stuck RIDE 1.5.2.1 running on Python 2.7.15.  and also it is in windows-10

Comment: I am Executing the 10-20 different suites in the same format of above code, in order to know the status of the test-suites whether they all are passing and later using the status of these suites, to generate some other logic in the ending, entire codes are being executed from ride itself

Comment: You need to tell us what is the version of Robot Framework, and if you can run without problems on the command line.